# Synergy setup problem

Tags: networking, synergy

I have one desktop and one laptop at home and want to combine them using synergy. I followed the instructions https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynergyHowto but failed to merge screens. The log says the server is waiting for clients, and my laptop failed to connect to the server with "timed out" error.

Both machines are on ubuntu 14.04.1 and the desktop is connected with wire and the laptop is using wireless. Both connections come from the same home router. I tried QuickSynergy as well but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out the machines' ip address and configure them in /etc/hosts.  Then use the name you assign to the ip's as for your configuration.

Synergy searching for an /etc/synergy.conf file first and will use this by default if it fines it.  Having a this file you can start the server just by running synergys on the commandline.

```
$ synergys
```

This is a basic synergy.conf to get you started:
/etc/synergy.conf:

```
section: screens
        desktop:
        laptop:                                                                                    
end
section: links
        desktop:
                right = laptop
        laptop:
                left = desktop
end
```

You can name the specifications desktop and laptop any name.  I gave them this name for example.  As long as you place the specified names in the /etc/hosts file, they will be found.

/etc/hosts:

```
# Lines appended to the host file
192.168.1.100     desktop
192.168.1.101     laptop
```

You can start the client by running this cli on the laptop:

```
$ /usr/bin/synergyc -n laptop desktop
```

The "-n" is telling the server your guest machine name is "laptop".  This is an added assurance of the host recognizing who is contacting.  By the way, using the specification might be all you need for your original problem.

Using this resolution should quickly work and get you started.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but your solution didn't work unfortunately. Perhaps is it related to the encryption mode that I enabled previously? I followed your solution but nothing happened....

Comment: Oops! The reason was because I enabled the firewall. Your configuration was correct. Not sure my previous configuration was also correct...